# Runscope: Using variables when asserting XML body

Tags: xml, xpath, runscope

I'm using `runscope` and am facing a problem with using variables in `xpath`.
Imagine I receive a response in the XML form and wish to check if `/AllTickets/Ticket[TicketId/text()=12345]/Name/text()` is equal to `somename`.

It works just fine, as long as I use `hardcoded values`. However, I'd like to be able to pass the value of `TicketId` as a variable and cannot do that - apparently the variable `ticket_id` (defined earlier in the test) cannot be substituted with its value.

That's what I tried:

```
/AllTickets/Ticket[TicketId/text()={{ticket_id}}]/Name/text()
or
/AllTickets/Ticket[TicketId/text()=$ticket_id]/Name/text()
```

There's no problem with the variable itself - if I try to use it in the expected results of the Assertions section, it's substituted just fine.

So, the question is: how can I use variables in xpath part of the XML verification?

Comment: I don't think we support variables in the property of an assertion. We can look into this, but can you email help@runscope.com with a shared result we can take a closer look at?